# Change the colors used in pgf-umlcd

Tags: color, pgf-umlcd

Is it possible to change the colors used in the `pgf-umlcd` package used to model UML class diagrams? The default yields a yellow background and a red border. However I'd like to use black and white diagrams (`bg=white, border=black`).
It is probably possible by changing the `tikz`-settings, but I'm not familiar with that.

Example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{class}{MyClass}{0, 0}
        \operation{myMethod(arg : ArgClass)}
    \end{class}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer by looking at the source-code at [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf-umlcd).

Change the text color:

```
\renewcommand{\umltextcolor}{black}
```

Change the border color:

```
\renewcommand{\umldrawcolor}{black}
```

Change the background color:

```
\renewcommand{\umlfillcolor}{white}
```

Comment: These settings are now added to the manual of `pgp-umlcd`.